# Marquee effect in Ionic

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to get a marquee like effect in ionic, where the text scrolls automatically across the screen. It works smoothly on web simulator, but once I load onto iPhone, the automatic scrolling becomes extremely choppy and not smooth at all. I was wondering if there is a fix to this, or if there's a native ionic component that supports a similar feature.

At the moment, I'm just simply using the marquee tag, I understand its deprecated, but I can't find an alternative. I've seen the ionic-marquee plugin someone made, but it only supports text, whereas I am scrolling more than just text. Using Angular with typescript, prefer no jQuery.

Thank you for your help!

```
<div class = "example1">
        <div class = "horizontalWSpace">
              <div  *ngFor ="let category of categories">
                  <h3 (click)="searchKeyword(category)" >{{category}} </h3>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

edit: I've tried using CSS animation, but it just overlaps all the ngfor elements ontop of each other.

```
.horizontalWSpace {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top:20px;
}

.example1 {
  height: 50px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
 }
 .example1 h3 {
  color: white;
  background-color:black;
  padding-left:12px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  margin: 5px;

  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  /* Starting position */
  -moz-transform:translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform:translateX(100%);   
  transform:translateX(100%);
  /* Apply animation to this element */ 
  -moz-animation: example1 5s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: example1 5s linear infinite;
  animation: example1 5s linear infinite;
 }
 /* Move it (define the animation) */
 @-moz-keyframes example1 {
  0%   { -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }
  100% { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes example1 {
  0%   { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
 }
```

Comment: Can you share the code example for the custom "marquee" code you tried?

Comment: [Is this what you were referencing?](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-marquee). I see <li> tags on the example page. Give it a try maybe it can handle divs.

Comment: @shadoe2020 I've tried using that, but it only allows for vertical animation, whereas I'd like it to be horizontal across the page.

Comment: @Claudiu I've added the code for the custom CSS animation, but it doesn't seem to work as it just bundles all the parts of the ngFor together and doesn't animate them separately.

Comment: @sanchg I thought that you might have tried to animate the position by manipulating the positioning in a loop manually instead of transforms which would have explained the choppiness. I'll try to repro when I get some time and see what's going on, but it should definitely be fixable with CSS alone.

Answer (score 0):

I Find Solution from [LINK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-marquee)

> ionic-marquee
>   **npm install ionic-marquee --save**

```
    @NgModule({
     ...
     imports: [
       IonMarqueeModule,
       ...
     ],
     ...
    })
    export class AppModule {}


    =======================================
    export class YourPage implements OnInit {
      horizontalText = `this is the text to show scroll horizontal, 
      and default is scroll horizontal. you don't need to set the direction`;
      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

      ngOnInit() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.horizontalText = `this is the text to show that text could be refreshed. 
          but this feature support horizontal scroll only!`;
        }, 5000);
      }
    }

======================

      <ion-marquee speed="30" style="height: 24px" [text]="horizontalText">
      </ion-marquee>
```